# Convert SQL query into mongodb

Tags: mongodb

What is the MongoDB equivalent for the following SQL query?

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  group_concat('signals')
FROM signals
GROUP BY station_id
```

i need to group by "station id", and concat "signal", thanks, the result would be like that:

```
| station_id | signals |
     321       2,3,5,2
```

Comment: Please share of table data in jsoneditor online

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9bfba1557ddd40ca9db67fd2038ad923, i need to group by "station id", and concat "signal", thanks

Comment: Please add multiple record in table after sending me links

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=9bfba1557ddd40ca9db67fd2038ad923 - There are three documents here

Comment: Please check result of group by in mongodb 
https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=bf9564f3646f4b0a866927c6f257d41e

Comment: the result is right, but where is the query itself?

Comment: But already got solution

Comment: anyway thank for the help

Comment: Any problem in mongodb  please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Please refer following aggregate query as an equivalent query of SQL into Mongodb

```
db.signals.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$station_id',
                signals: {
                    $push: '$signal'
                }
            }
        },

    ]

);
```